# Undefined reference to vtable when inheriting QFrame

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt 5.4 x86 on Windows 8.1 Pro x64. Following [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-elidedlabel.html) I'm trying to implement an `ElidedLabel` class. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the code in the example itself is producing

```
error: undefined reference to `vtable for ElidedLabel'
```

What's wrong and how to fix it? I've checked the [Qt 5.4 documentation of `QFrame`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qframe.html) and there is not a pure virtual function that needs to be defined.

Comment: Maybe moc don't preprocess your code, so try the Build > Run qmake command from the menu.

Comment: @Chernobyl: yes it works! Can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moc` (`Meta Object Compiler`) didn't preprocess your code, so you get this not very clear error.

Solution: try the `Build > Run qmake` command from the menu. This command will run `moc` and it will generate correct code for your class.